# Empty square appear at the end of every resources

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, nexus-s

On **Nexus S, Android 2.3.3** A little empty square appear at the end of every resources on the page.
The resources come from a `.resx` file in **Visual Studio 2010**.
I verified, there is no empty space at the end or line break.
Anyone have an idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `<br>` after the resource in the markup.
Make sur to keep the **resource and markup on the same line**.
**Good**

```
<%= Resources.ResourceName %><br>
```

**Bad**

```
<%= Resources.ResourceName %>
<br>
```